# Java [TCG Project] - Implementing cards effect with a tokenized String

Tags: java

I'm currently workig on a TCG (Trading Card Game) project using Java and I'm in front of a big problem: implement a card effect. Now, I have figured out how can I do this, but I'm having some troubles with the code. 
My idea was to store in a String some kind of commands code, with specific keywords. For example: "damage [target] [value]" will allows me to damage a player or a creature with the specified value, "draw [target] [numberOfCards]" will allows me to make a player draw from his deck a certain number of cards, "check [field] [player] [condition]" will allows me to check if on the field of a player will be ceratin number of cards or a specific creature etc. 
I have created a class called Skill which is:

```
public class Skill {

    private String type;
    private int cost;
    private String desc;
    private String commands;

    public Skill(String type, int cost, String desc, String commands) {
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.commands = commands;
    }

    public void use() {
        SkillManager.executeCommands(commands);
    }

}
```

Now, I want to SkillManager class to interpret and excexute the commands given as parameters int the executeCommands method. With keywords like "damage", "check", "draw", etc. I'm ok, but my problem is: how can I actually replace the field string with the actual Objects I want to work with? And how can I actually select the object? I was thinking of using the method .toString() for every object and make a method in the GameTable class which returns the Object with the Srting equals to the one I given, but I can't figured it out how can I implement this.

Tips are appreciated. Thank you and sorry for my BAD english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a design pattern that can help you out, and its called Interpreter.

Checkout this link for what i'm talking about: [Interpreter Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/interpreter_pattern.htm)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you mate, I'm watchin at the tutorial and seems useful for this problem.
Really appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If you can solve your problem with this pattern, accept this answer so more people can see it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. Have I to mark the "check" sign?